# How to apply default preference style to a custom preference?

Tags: android, styles, preference

I am developing a custom preference for my Settings menu. Basically it has a title and a seekBar.

I created a layout for the MyPreference it looks so different than e.g. CheckBoxPreference.

How could I apply the style of CheckBoxPreference to MyPreference? (Textviews, intention etc)

Here is an image about how it looks like now: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/130808/352269895Untitled_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing this yourself, follow this guide, they include a lot of code to help you... http://robobunny.com/wp/2011/08/13/android-seekbar-preference/

You can then further customize it using http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks the robobunny sets up the style manually instead of somehow inherit it from the OS. Is there any way to inheritation?

Comment: I don't believe so, instead of figuring it out yourself, I would just follow the instructions in the post